# PHP self submitting form to insert rows into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a PHP self submitting form which inserts row into a MySQL table.
Here is the code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","calendar","calendar");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ecalendar", $con);

$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$title = $start.'-'.$end;

$sql="INSERT INTO events (title, description, evdate) VALUES ('$title','$_POST[description]','$_POST[evdate]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);

}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Form Input Data</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#evdate").datepicker();
});
$(function () {
    $("#start").timepicker();
});
$(function () {
    $("#end").timepicker();
});
</script>
</head>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<p>Interval Orar</p>

<input type="text" id="start" name="start" />
<input type="text" id="end" name="end" />
        
<p>Data
<br />
<input type="text" id="evdate" name="evdate" />
</p>
<p>Eveniment
<br />
<textarea name='description'></textarea>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can fill in the form, click on the button, but nothing happens. Not even an error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following like

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

you are inserting only if submit named data is there

ie

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use $_POST['submit'] without having a name on the submit form input, so use the inputs to check if the form is set.

```
            if(isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['end']) && isset($_POST['evdate']) && isset($_POST['description']))
```

Comment: Also, in your query, you need to add quotes to your superglobals, $_POST[\'desription\']